# Is it a good practice to keep the search query after the user selected the result?

Tags: search, search-results, flow

I'm designing a search flow for an app, and I have a doubt about what to do after the user select an item from the result list and then click the back button. For example:

1. This is the search screen, which brings all the items available:

[image]

2. This is the screen with the search term:

[image]

3. This is the screen for the item the user selected:

[image]

My question is, after the user click the back button on the trird screen, should it go back to first screen, with clean search query, or to the second screen, with the search query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to go back to the second screen, for two reasons:

- "Back" is a historical step for me, so I really want to get back to the last step before the current one.
- If I determine in step 3 that this is not the item I was searching for, I need to go back to the result list to pick the next potential candidate. This implies that you will have to restore the scroll position (and selection, if any) in the result list if you go back.

Comment: +1 Without other cues from the user about what their intention is, taking them back to the first screen would result in the loss of existing information (i.e. the search term) and the cost of pressing the back button once more compared to having to type the search term is going to be less in most cases.